# Minimum column value if two other columns match

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, min

I have an excel file with data A, B & C.

I want to find the min of C but only if corresponding A=B.

How can I perform this operation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with an array formula¹.

```
=min(if(A2:A34=B2:B34, C2:C34))
```

Array formulas should never be full column references, If the columns of numbers grows and shrinks occasionally, apply the following to dynamically adjust the number of cells referenced.

```
=min(if(A2:index(A:A, match(1e99, C:C))=B2:index(B:B, match(1e99, C:C)), C2:index(C:C, match(1e99, C:C))))
```

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: My apologies; I originally wrote that missing a bracket and with A43 instead of A34. It has been corrected above.

Comment: ok it working with min but when i am trying to find maximum with same condition . its giving maximum of C without if condition. i wrote =MAX(IF(A2:A34=B2:B34, C2:C34)). It gives 122  instead of 5.

Comment: Hmmm... I just tested it and it works fine by swapping MIN for MAX (remember the [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter]). [edit] just tested without CSE and it returns the column max without conditions so you probably didn't CSE.

Comment: thank you it works with [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter]. Is it necessary to press [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter] for all excel formula?

Comment: Only array formulas. The CSE applies an extra level of processing so it isn't A:A=B2, it is A:A=B:B. See the link I provided in the footnote.

Comment: I used same way to find maximum from data (which have 260101 data entry). It's giving wrong answer. Why this happening?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is giving the wrong answer but I'm pretty sure I would hesitate before using an array formula on 260K rows. If you are having trouble with specific data, make the data available through a link to a google spreadsheet or something similar. I cannot debug 260K rows of data without seeing it.